# Problem adding a url with "&" character at Openload API

Tags: api

I use Openload API (https://openload.co/api) to add a remote upload link
but when i want to add a URL with "&" character inside it got a problem and can't add the full link

for example when I add a URL like "http://example.com/test.zip&token=1234" it adds only "http://example.com/test.zip"

According to their API , I know why this problem occur but I want to ask is their any way to solve it?

Comment: Replace ampersand with %26, the url encoded version of an ampersand.